# Use commons java logging in spring mvc by default

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, apache-commons-logging

I want use the default log system that comes with **spring mvc**, I have this code.

```
protected final Log LOGGER = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

@RequestMapping("/editor")
public String init() {
    LOGGER.debug("[EditorController.init] - Inicio");
    return TILES + "editor";
}
```

When you goes to `/editor` in my **webapp**, I dont see logged info in any output. I have a commons-loggin.properties in my resources folder (`/src/resources`) and I have this propertie setted (I tried without any config too)

```
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

# default log level
.level=INFO
```

All info that I see on the net, change the method to `SLF4J` or `L4J`, I don't want use any new library, my Log use will be very simple, I think that commons-logging can works great.

Any help?

Comment: Your log level is set at `Info`, so debug logs won't appear in the console

Comment: not works with any type of loggin